# Issue Importing ConfigParser Read File

Tags: python, linux

**Intro**:
I have a .ini file (*A*) which stores specific credentials.  There are multiple scripts (*B*) - of python, php, etc - which parse this .ini file (*A*) into variables and are also in the same directory as the .ini file (*A*).  Other scripts (*C*) under another directory (not a subdirectory) where the .ini file (*A*) and the parsing scripts (*B*) do NOT reside import/include these parsing scripts (*B*) to take advantage of the parsed, credential variables.

However, I'm getting this error "ConfigParser.NoSectionError" when trying to run a python script (*C*) using **"sudo python <_(*C*)_>.py"**.
Running **"sudo python"**/interactive python, and importing the python parsing script (*B*) while in the directory of the .ini file (*A*) and (*B*), I'm able to access the parsed, credential variables.

**Question**:
What am I doing wrong? I believe it to be a permission issue.

**Folder Tree**:

Folder_0
    ->Sub_Folder_0
        ->(*A*)
        ->(*B*)
    ->Sub_Folder_1
        ->(*C*)

(*A*)

```
  [Host]
  ip = 111.111.1.222
  [Schema]
  name = Derp_A_Der
  [User]
  name = root
  password = SexysBack
```

(*B*)

```
   import ConfigParser as CP;
   config = CP.ConfigParser();
   config.read("B.ini");

   m_p = config.get("User", "password");
   m_h = config.get("Host", "ip");
   m_n = config.get("Schema", "name");
   m_u = config.get("User", "name");
```

(*C*)

```
   import sys;
   import os;

   mysql_config_path = "/Folder_0/Sub_Folder_0/";
   sys.path.append( os.path.abspath(mysql_config_path) );
   import mysqlConfig as myC;

   print myC.m_u;
```

Comment: It looks like you are reading different ini files and get different results. You can check which sections you have by adding  "print config.sections() " after reading config.

Comment: I can't print that off due to the fact that it fails before it goes further.  I don't think it is actually finding the .ini file or is unable to read the .ini file; I'm guessing the latter

Comment: And also before reading you can check in which folder exactly you are: by "  print os.getcwd()"

Comment: So, where exactly you get exception? I assume in one of config.get(), so add after config.read()

Comment: Correct and yes, thanks for pointing that out.  I'm still under the _Sub_Folder_1_

Comment: Thanks, I Think i'll be able to fix it.

Comment: such a stupid mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When config file is not found, the empty dataset will be used, thus you get exception *NoSectionError*
You should change directory to where your config file is located before running script with

```
os.chdir(mysql_config_path)
```

or use the full path in the target script (in config.read())

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **pmod**, I've realized I was making a stupid mistake.  I was still under _Sub_Folder_1_.

**Solution 1**:
Change (*C*) to...

```
import sys;
import os;

mysql_config_path = "/Folder_0/Sub_Folder_0/";
os.chdir(mysql_config_path);
sys.path.append( os.path.abspath(mysql_config_path) );
import mysqlConfig as myC;

print myC.m_u;
```

**Solution 2**:
Change (*B*) to...

```
import ConfigParser as CP;
config = CP.ConfigParser();
config.read("/Folder_0/Sub_Folder_0/B.ini");

m_p = config.get("User", "password");
m_h = config.get("Host", "ip");
m_n = config.get("Schema", "name");
m_u = config.get("User", "name");
```